# How to Import CSV data from FTP server directory into Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, cron

I would like to run every 6 hours, from a cron, a PHP script (or whatever else) that would update a MySQL table from a csv file present in FTP server.

What CSV Import/Export is very interesting, but I would like it to pick the CSV file from a directory instead of manually uploading it, because the name of the file will change: `logdata_*******.csv`).

Has anyone done such a thing ? Is it easily possible ? 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: 1) Get the file (file_get_content vs cURL) 2) LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: Can you provide me the code snippet for same? I am very new to this and 've been juggling a lot with the same.

Comment: I wouldn't mind giving you a snippet if I had something available, but I don't have time to write the snippet for you. What I can guarantee though, is with your own efforts you will be able to teach yourself how to write what you described. I know that because I was once in your position. Google the terms I suggested in my previous comment, and you'll understand how to write it.

Comment: Thanks a lot dayulioli! I ll consider that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a php script that will guide you, you need to change it to your needs, I've put some explanations into it:

If you want to do this with ftp, you will also need to establish a ftp connection.

```
$db_connection = new mysqli("HOST","DB_USER","DB_PASS","DB"); // make mysqli connection to DB

$query = $db_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO yourtable (column1,column2) VALUES (?,?)");

$data = scandir('/PATH/TO/READ'); // Scan the dir your files are in

foreach ($data as $datas) {

if (0 === strpos($datas, 'logdata')) {

   echo $datas."<br />"; //Show all the files that beginn with logdata

$file = 'PATH/TO/FILE/'.$datas;
unset($file[0]); //DELETE THE FIRST LINE IF FILE CONTAINS A HEADLINE ELSE DELETE THIS LINE
foreach ($file as $line) 
{ 
   $column = explode("\t", $line);  // \t stands for tab-delimited, change it to what ever delimites your file (f.e. ; , . )

$example = $column[0]; // get content of first column
$example1 = $column[1]; // get content of second column
// .....          
$query->bind_param('ss',$example, $example1)
$query->execute();


}}}
```

Let's call the file insertscript.php, then your cronjob would be:

```
0 */6 * * * nohup php /path/to/file/insertscript.php
```

nohup put's the proccess to the background and creates a file for every run. If you don't want this file, you can alter your cronjob to:

```
0 */6 * * * nohup php /path/to/file/insertscript.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: does this look for the latest file in the directory or simply process all csv with logdata?